# Refreshing Database VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, instant-messaging

So I have instant messaging functionality that I use with a database. Each time a message is sent it prints what's in the message column in the database into a rich text box in my vb.net application

My problem is. I have to click on the "send message" button twice to get the functionality to work, as the first time I click it, nothing happens

Does anyone have any idea where I'm gone wrong? Much appreciated!

```
 Try
        '----------------Sends the message-------------------------------------
        MysqlConn.Open() ' opening the connection to the DB
        Dim query As String
        query = "insert into dojodb.chats (Message) values ('" & txtMessage.Text & "')"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader 'executes the command and reads data from db
        reader.Close()


        '-------------------Retreives the message------------------------------------
        Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT * FROM chats"
        Dim chatcommand As New MySqlCommand(sqlStr, MysqlConn)
        Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader = chatcommand.ExecuteReader()
        Dim tbl As New DataTable
        tbl.Load(rdr)


        '-------For every row, print the message, skip a line, and add 1 so it goes to next msg--------
        For i As Integer = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
            rowIndex = i
            strOutPut &= CStr(tbl.Rows(rowIndex)("Message")) & vbNewLine
            i = i + 1
        Next

        txtGroupChat.Text = strOutPut
        strOutPut = "" 'clearing the string so that it does not print out duplicate info next time

        '-------------------------End Retrieve-------------------------------------------

        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) 'printing the exact error to help future testing if needed
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but in case you're not aware of it, you may want to read up on  [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Also, I have a field called "pk" that auto increments each time a message is saved to the database. This is the primary key, and is used to sort the messages by oldest-newest to print to the text box

Comment: @JamesThorpe , my database is safe. I didnt reveal any sensitive connection info

Comment: You don't need connection info for SQL Injection.  Imagine someone types the message `oops') go drop table dojodb.chats go` into the chat message.  I suggest you think about it before you try it...

Comment: Haha true, never thought of it that way, thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is this section:

```
'-------For every row, print the message, skip a line, and add 1 so it goes to next msg--------
For i As Integer = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
    rowIndex = i
    strOutPut &= CStr(tbl.Rows(rowIndex)("Message")) & vbNewLine
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Why are you skipping a line?  This will cause every other message in the table to not be written out, and therefore that's why you have to press it twice so that it shows up.  You don't need to manually increment the indexer in a `For` loop, I suggest you try this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
    rowIndex = i
    strOutPut &= CStr(tbl.Rows(rowIndex)("Message")) & vbNewLine
Next
```